# Force on a point charge in the cavity of an uncharged conductor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, conductors

There's another question on this particular topic, more specifically my doubts arise from dealing with problem $2.40$ of Griffiths' *Electrodynamics* (4th ed). I've read some answers and they all refer to the solution of Laplace's equation in the absence of any charge and also *Earnshaw's theorem*, which I'd like to leave apart for I don't have the necessary knowledge yet. My approach is: 
I first consider a conductor whose boundary we can call $\Sigma_1$, with a cavity inside (the boundary of the latter I called $\Sigma_2$). Inside the cavity, there's a positive point charge $+q$. Now the induced positive surface charge densities (which are both not uniform) on the outer surface of the conductor $\Sigma_1$ is such that:
$$ q =  \int\int_{\Sigma_1}\sigma_+(\mathbf{r'})d\mathbf{a'}$$
Equivalently, for $\Sigma_2$:
$$ -q = \int\int_{\Sigma_2}\sigma_-(\mathbf{r'})d\mathbf{a'}$$
Now for my purposes, I can consider a conductor very large, let's say that it extends to infinity. In this way, I can ignore the contribution to the net electrical field inside the cavity since the charges are infinitely far away.
I know that the point charge inside the cavity generates a radial field, but I also know that the charge cannot exert a non-null force on itself. So we have the general formula:
$$ \mathbf{F}_q = q\mathbf{E}^{ext}_{net}$$
The only contribution to the field comes from the induced negative surface charge on the boundary of the cavity $\Sigma_2$: 
$$\mathbf{E}^{ext} = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \int_{\Sigma_2} \frac{\sigma_{-}(\mathbf{r}') }{r'^2 } \mathbf{\hat{r}} da'$$
In the last integral we set the origin of our coordinate system at the place where the point charge is, so that $\mathbf{r-r'} = -\mathbf{r'}$. 
Now it's easy to see that this field plus the one due to the point charge must cancel each other (otherwise the field inside the meat of the conductor wouldn't be null). But this obviously does not allow me to assume that the field is such that it generates a null force on the point charge, unless the whole configuration presents some kind of simmetry.
Therefore, in general, the point charge will experience a non-null force and this means it will be dragged towards some part of the cavity (yes I know the force can also be repulsive sometimes, in any case the charge will move inside the cavity). This all seemed a pretty good argument to me exect for one thing: aren't we in the regime of electrostatics where all the charge is stationary? Isn't this contradictory? 
My other doubt is:
let us suppose that the cavity is spherical (the origin of our coordinate system coinciding with the point charge inside it). Can I assume that the induced charge $\sigma_{-}$ will spread uniformly on the boundary of the cavity? Or is there some weird configuration which could minimize the potential energy of the configuration even more? Because if this isn't the case, then we have found (one of the possible ) configuration(s) in which the force on the charge is exactly zero, since $\mathbf{E} = 0$ inside the cavity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This all seemed a pretty good argument to me exect for one thing: aren't we in the regime of electrostatics where all the charge is stationary? Isn't this contradictory?

No. Electrostatics *assumes* charges are at rest, but it does not imply they are at stable rest due to all electric forces acting on any single charged particle cancelling each other. Purely electrostatic system of charged particles (no other forces present) is always unstable, whatever the spatial configuration of charges. This is because electric potential due to other charges, "experienced" by any test charge, cannot have a minimum or a maximum at any point of space; such potential obeys the Laplace equation, which prevents such minimum/maximum from existing anywhere in infinite space. Potential everywhere is such that it either 1) increases in certain direction, and decreases in the opposite one (a test charge there would be in unstable position, pushed by electric force) or 2) it does not change with position at all (a test charge there would be in indifferent position, not pushed by electric force). In case 2, it looks like the test particle could be at rest, experiencing zero net electric force. This is the case of system that has only 1 particle. However, if there are other particles, it is not possible to have them all at magic points where they experience zero net electric field.

There have to be other, non-electrostatic, forces acting on the particles, to have a system of two or more charges that is in equilibrium. In your example, charge on the surfaces is stabilized by internal forces of the metal, keeping the charge motion only to the metal, preventing it from jumping out to vacuum.

> let us suppose that the cavity is spherical (the origin of our coordinate system coinciding with the point charge inside it). Can I assume that the induced charge $\sigma_{-}$ will spread uniformly on the boundary of the cavity? Or is there some weird configuration which could minimize the potential energy of the configuration even more? Because if this isn't the case, then we have found (one of the possible ) configuration(s) in which the force on the charge is exactly zero, since $\mathbf{E} = 0$ inside the cavity.

Surface charge will have uniform area density only in case the charge inside is at the exact center of the spherical cavity.

This situation is unstable, because it takes arbitrarily small shift of the charge inside to make the configuration non-equilibrium. The shifted charge inside induces asymmetric distribution on the inner surface which will attract the charge inside towards the cavity wall.

Comment: I think I’m confusing minimal of potential energy with a point of stable equilibrium where basically the particles somehow could oscillate around the point where the potential energy attains its minimum but it is bound to go back to it. You stated that the potential $V$ can’t attain  maxima or minima, therefore it must be constant inside the perfectly spherical cavity with the particle at its center. but if it is then we are in case (2). How can it be unstable if it is a point of indifferent equilibrium, why would it be dragged towards the boundary? It seems like the two are in constrast

Comment: If the potential is constant inside the cavity (from Laplace’s equation) then the electric field is null inside the cavity so the charge experiences no force at all. But how can you show that even the smallest perturbation can alter the equilibrium? What I’m saying is: constant potential is equivalent to indifferent equilibrium (case 2). But this cannot be true since we have more than one particle. Thus what equilibrium configuration are we in initially? And how do you prove that a small perturbation will alter the configuration permanently and make it unstable?

Comment: If the charge on the inside surface was somehow kept uniformly distributed, then the system would be in indifferent equilibrium. But since that distribution is determined by position of the charge inside, any displacement of the charge will affect also that distribution. Conductor in general attracts charge due to electrostatic induction, so the inner charge will be attracted in direction of the shortest path to the cavity surface.

Comment: Another way to see this is to realize that even in asymmetric configuration, all points on the spherical cavity will always have the same potential, which means electric field inside is the same as that of two charges of opposite sign: one the inner charge, one the imaginary charge outside the cavity, that simulates the cavity distribution.